# Java Tetris - weird row clearing issue

Tags: java, swing

I’m encountering a couple weird things with clearing rows in Tetris...

If I set my board’s width and height to be the same (10 and 10):

```
board = new Board(10, 10, 35);
```

which are determined by:

```
public Board(int w, int h, int ts) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    tilesize = ts;
    grid = new Tile[width][height];
...
}

public int getWidth() {
       return width * tilesize; 
}

public int getHeight() {
       return height * tilesize;
}
```

Row clearing seems to work fine (although, I’m not sure why there is a hidden row beneath it… shouldn’t it fit perfectly into the JFrame?):

[image][image]

But if I set my width and height differently (here it’s 10 and 12),  the rows won’t clear.

```
board = new Board(10, 12, 35);
```

[image]

Row clearing:

```
public void checkBottomFull() {
    System.out.println(grid.length);
    int lines = 0;
    for(int row = grid.length-1; row >= 0; row--) {
        while (isFull(row)) {       
            lines++;
            clearRow(row);   
        }
    }
}

public boolean isFull(int row) {
    for (int col = 0; col <= grid[row].length-1; col++) {
        while(grid[col][row] == null) {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void clearRow(int rowToClear) {
     for(int row = rowToClear; row > 0; row--) {
         for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            grid[col][row] = grid[col][row-1];
         }
     }
}
```

Any thoughts why having equal dimensions allows the rows to clear? Why should that matter?

Thanks!

---

I think I found the issue, but when I tried to resolve it, it now throws an error.

Before, I had `checkBottomFull()` looping through grid.length-1, which was equal to 10 ( `for(int row = grid.length-1; row >= 0; row--) {`) But I put height (rows) as 12 `gameBoard = new Board(10, 12, 35);`, so I should be looping through 12 rows, not 10. And I should be looping through 10 columns per row...

So I hardcoded the rows at 12 and columns at 10 below...

```
//loop through all rows (12 rows)
public void checkBottomFull() {
    System.out.println(grid.length);
    for(int row = 12; row > 0; row--) {
        while (isFull(row)) {       
            clearRow(row);   
        }
    }
}
//loop through all columns in that row (10 columns)
public boolean isFull(int row) {
    System.out.println(grid[row].length);
    for (int col = 0; col <= 10; col++) {
        if(grid[col][row] == null) {
             return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it's throwing an IndexOutOfBounds exception...

No idea why

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You are almost certainly swapping `col` and `row` in an array index somewhere you should not be.

Comment: annnnnnnnd I am singing the tetris song. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is this:

```
for (int col = 0; col <= grid[row].length-1; col++) {
    while(grid[col][row] == null) {
```

You've got `grid[row]` but then `grid[col][row]`. This leads me to think it should either be `grid[col]` or grid[row][col]`

Comment: I pass in `row` to isFull (which loops through a column based on that row) each time checkBottomFull loops through a row

Comment: I made edits above. I think I found the issue but don't know how to resolve error

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the grid/column maxes for your loops swapped out somewhere. It works fine when it's square as they would be the same. If it's not square (ie the row/column maxes are different) then for one side it wouldn't process the entire row/column and the other would overflow.

Unrelated, but what's the point of the `while(grid[col][row] == null)` loop in the `isFull(...)` method? Should this be an `if` instead?

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally left that in there because I originally had `if (isFull(row)) { `, so I needed to `while` within `isFull()`. But then changed `if (isFull(row)) { ` to `while (isFull(row)) { `

Comment: I made edits above. I think I found the issue but don't know how to resolve error

Comment: You still have the indexes swapped. In your latest `isFull(...)` you have `grid[col][row] = ...`. Shouldn't that be `grid[row][col]`? A two dimensional array is an "array of arrays" so if `grid.length` refers to the number of rows (that's what it looks like based on the `checkBottomFull()` method) then `grid[x]` is row X, not column X.

Comment: `grid.length` was returning 10, which is what I've specified for the number of columns (width), not rows (height). I changed `if(grid[col][row] == null) {` to `if(grid[row][col] == null) {` and it's throwing Index Out of Bounds exception: 12.

Comment: The board creation is wrong. You have width/height reversed. It should be `grid = new Tile[height][width]`.

Comment: yeah haha I'm fixing that now. I'll see if it fixes that.

Comment: I've been unable to fix the issue even with making it `Tile[height][width]... I've posted an Sscce here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363307/java-tetris-confused-on-gridrowcol-and-coordinates-x-y