# Java Tetris - Confused on grid[row][col] and coordinates (x, y)

Tags: java, swing

I'm making Tetris in java for fun... I pretty much had everything working... but later found out that when I wanted to change the dimensions so it was square ([10 row][10 col] matrix, but instead a [12 row][10 col] matrix), that I started getting Index Out of Bound exceptions... see here: [Java Tetris - weird row clearing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342928/java-tetris-weird-row-clearing-issue)

So I tried fixing everything so that the rows and columns weren't flip flopped... But am now getting hung up on the fact that the grid takes [row][col], but I’m moving around the tiles as (x, y) coordinates…

What’s confusing me is that row = y and col = x… which is reversed… so when I pass in coordinates I’m not sure when to swap them.

I know it’s a simple thing, but it’s confusing the hell out of me and I keep getting out of bounds exceptions whenever I think I have it right.

I'm not sure where the exact issue is, so I'm posting a full Sscce of my program... I think the issue is in the Board class...

Here, the block should still be able to move down... but if it tries to go down further than this... 
[image]

I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Board.getTileAt(Board.java:177)
    at Tile.collision(Tile.java:31)
    at Piece.isCollision(Piece.java:172)
    at Board.collisionCheck(Board.java:192)
    at Piece.movePieceCheck(Piece.java:87)
    at Board.keyPressed(Board.java:160)
```

**Sscce:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MainSscce extends JPanel {
       static MainSscce runMe;
       BoardSscce gameBoard, scoreBoard;

       public MainSscce() {    //creates a new frame window and sets properties
              JFrame f = new JFrame("Tetris");
              //width (height), length, tilesize
              gameBoard = new BoardSscce(12, 10, 35);
             // scoreBoard = new BoardSscce(10, 10, 35);
              f.add(gameBoard);
              f.setSize(gameBoard.getWidth(), gameBoard.getHeight());
              f.setVisible(true);
              f.setResizable(false);
              f.setVisible(true);
              f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
              Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
              //set j frame location to appear in middle of screen
              f.setLocation( (screensize.width - f.getWidth())/2,
                   (screensize.height - f.getHeight())/2-100 );
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              runMe = new MainSscce();
       }

}


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.event.*; // for ActionListener and ActionEvent
import java.util.Random;

public class BoardSscce extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private TileSscce grid[][];
    private int totalRows, totalCols, tilesize, level, totalScore;
    private final int changeLevelMultiplier;
    private PieceSscce newPiece, nextPiece;
    private String randomPiece;
    private boolean gameLost;

    public BoardSscce(int r, int c, int ts) {
        totalRows = r;
        totalCols = c;
        tilesize = ts;
        //set grid size to [# rows][# columns], aka [height][width]
        grid = new TileSscce[totalRows][totalCols];
        gameLost = false;

        System.out.println("TotalRows: " + totalRows + ", " + "TotalCols: " + totalCols);

        //multiplier to determine what score the level changes, which is:
        //level * changeLevelMultiplier;
        changeLevelMultiplier = 40;

        //initialize score to 0
        totalScore = 0;

        //initialize level to 0
        level = 0;

        newPiece = new PieceSscce(this, randomPiece(), getColor());
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        //getTranspose();

        timer();

    }

    public String randomPiece() {
        String[] Pieces = {"L", "O", "Z", "RevZ", "Bar", "T", "RevL"};

        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * Pieces.length);
        randomPiece = Pieces[rand];

        return randomPiece;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        Color color;
        if (randomPiece.equals("L")) 
            color = new Color(17, 255, 0);
        else if(randomPiece.equals("O"))
            color = new Color(117, 168, 255);
        else if(randomPiece.equals("Z"))
            color = new Color(255, 187, 82);
        else if(randomPiece.equals("RevZ"))
            color = new Color(206, 27, 72);
        else if(randomPiece.equals("Bar"))
            color = new Color(50, 216, 219);
        else if(randomPiece.equals("T"))
            color = new Color(252, 148, 240);
        else 
            color = new Color(255, 255, 52);    

        //Random rand = new Random();
        //float r = rand.nextFloat();
        //float g = rand.nextFloat();
        //float b = rand.nextFloat();
        //Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);

        return color;
    }

    //dimensions of board = width * tilesize
    public int getWidth() {
        return totalCols * tilesize; 
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return totalRows * tilesize;
    }

    public int getTileSize() {  
        return tilesize;
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                //System.out.println(row + ", " + col);
                g.drawString("[" + row + "][" + col + "]", col * tilesize, row * tilesize+10);
                System.out.println(row + ", " + col);
                //if there is a non-null space, that is a Tetris piece... fill it
                if(grid[row][col] != null) {            
                    g.setColor(grid[row][col].getColor());
                    g.fillRect(row * tilesize, col * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        }
        //  g.drawString("Level: " + level, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2-130);
        //  g.drawString("Score: " + totalScore, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2-100);

            if (gameLost == true) {
                g.drawString("Way to go, loser...", this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
                messageTimer();
            }
        }

    //Auto move piece
    public void timer () {
        int interval;
        switch (level) {
        //each level increases drop speed by .10 seconds
            case 1: interval = 800;
                    break;
            case 2: interval = 700;
                    break;
            case 3: interval = 600;
                    break;
            case 4: interval = 500;
                    break;
            default: interval = 1000;
                    break;
        }
        Timer t = new Timer(interval, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               //newPiece.autoMove();
               //repaint();
            }
         });
        t.start();
    }    

    public void messageTimer()   {
        Timer t = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gameLost = false;
            }
         });
        t.start();      
    }

    //move piece on key input
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        newPiece.movePieceCheck(e.getKeyCode());        
        repaint();  
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y) {
        return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < totalCols && y < totalRows; 
    }

    // returns the tile at (x, y) or null if empty
    public Tile getTileAt(int x, int y) {
        if(isValidCoordinate(x, y))
            return grid[x][y];
        return null;
    }

    // sets the tile at (x, y) to tile
    public void setTileAt(Tile tile, int x, int y) {
        if(isValidCoordinate(x, y))     
            grid[x][y] = tile;
    }

    public boolean isOpen(int x, int y) {
        return isValidCoordinate(x, y) && (getTileAt(x, y) == null);
    }

    public void collisionCheck() {
        if (newPiece.isCollision()){
            newPiece = new PieceSscce(this, randomPiece(), getColor());
        }       
    }

    public void changeLevel () {
        int max = (level+1)*changeLevelMultiplier;
        if (totalScore >= max) {
            System.out.println(max + "reached... next level");
            level++;
            totalScore = 0;
            timer();
        }
    }

    public int tallyScore(int totalLines) {
        int score = 0;
        switch (totalLines) {
            case 1: score = 40 * (level + 1);
                    break;
            case 2: score = 100 * (level + 1);
                    break;
            case 3: score = 300 * (level + 1);
                    break;
            case 4: score = 1200 * (level + 1);
                    break;
            default: break;
        }
        return score;
    }

    //loop through all rows starting at bottom (12 rows)
    public void checkBottomFull() {
        int lines = 0;
        for(int row = 12; row > 0; row--) {
        /*  while (isFull(row)) {       
                lines++;
               // clearRow(row);   
            }*/
        }
        totalScore += tallyScore(lines);    
        //check if level needs to be changed based on current score...
        changeLevel();
        //reset lines after score has been incremented
        lines=0;
    }
    //loop through all columns in that row (10 columns)
    public boolean isFull(int row) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= 10; col++) {
          System.out.println(row + ", " + col);
              if(grid[row][col] == null) {
                 return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clearRow(int rowToClear) {
         for(int row = rowToClear; row > 0; row--) {
             for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                grid[col][row] = grid[col][row-1];
             }
         }
    }

    public void checkEndGame(int x, int y) {
        //if currPiece y location = 0 AND the space below is filled... 
        if (y <= 2 && !isOpen(x, y+1)) {
            gameLost = true;
            level = 0;
            totalScore = 0;
            //reset timer
            timer();
            for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                    grid[row][col] = null;              
                }       
            }
        }       
    }
}




import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class PieceSscce {
    public int[] pieceCoordinates;
    public String shape, currRotation;
    public Color color;
    public BoardSscce board;    
    public int rotationsCounter;
    public TileSscce tile[];

    public int[] newPositionX, newPositionY, currPositionX, currPositionY;

    //don't need to pass in board because I'm already utilizing the Tiles class, which knows about the board
    public Piece(Board b, String randomPiece, Color randomColor) {
        shape = randomPiece;
        color = randomColor;
        board = b;

        newPositionX = new int[4];
        newPositionY = new int[4];
        currPositionX = new int[4];
        currPositionY = new int[4];
        pieceCoordinates = new int[8];


        //set pieceCoordinates global variable
        getShape(shape);
        tile = new TileSscce[4];

        int counterX = 0, counterY = 1;
        System.out.print("\"" + shape + "\" Coordinates: ");
        //generate 4 new Tiles at specified coordinates that will compose the Piece
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            tile[i] = new TileSscce(board, pieceCoordinates[counterX], pieceCoordinates[counterY]);
            System.out.print("(" + pieceCoordinates[counterX] + ", " + pieceCoordinates[counterY] + ") ");
            //increment by 2 because x,y values are next to each other in array
            counterX+=2;
            counterY+=2;    
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            tile[i].setColor(color);
        }
    }

    public void calcNewPosition(int newX, int newY, int currTile) {             
        newPositionX[currTile] = newX;
        newPositionY[currTile] = newY;
    }

    public void clearCurrPosition() {   
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            currPositionX[i] = tile[i].getX();
            currPositionY[i] = tile[i].getY();  
            board.setTileAt(null, currPositionX[i], currPositionY[i]);
        }   
    }       

    public void autoMove() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY()+1, i);                               
        }       
        clearCurrPosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            board.checkEndGame(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY());
            System.out.println("Checking..." + tile[i].getX() + ", " + tile[i].getY());
        }
        board.checkBottomFull();
        board.collisionCheck(); 
        move();
    }

    public void movePieceCheck(int keycode) {   
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                calcNewPosition(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY()+1, i);                               
            }       
            clearCurrPosition();
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                board.checkEndGame(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY());
                System.out.println("Checking..." + tile[i].getX() + ", " + tile[i].getY());
            }   
            board.checkBottomFull();
            board.collisionCheck(); 
            move();
        }
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                calcNewPosition(tile[i].getX()+1, tile[i].getY(), i);
            }       
            clearCurrPosition();
            move();
        }
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                calcNewPosition(tile[i].getX()-1, tile[i].getY(), i);
            }       
            clearCurrPosition();
            move();
        }
        //rotate left
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {     
            int[] rotatedCoords = calcRotation("left");
            clearCurrPosition();
            rotate(rotatedCoords, "left");
        }

        //rotate right
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            int[] rotatedCoords = calcRotation("right");
            clearCurrPosition();
            rotate(rotatedCoords, "right");     
        }
    }

    public boolean movePieceValid() {   
        boolean valid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            if(!tile[i].checkNewLocation(newPositionX[i], newPositionY[i])) 
                valid = false;

        }       
        return valid;
    }       

    public boolean validRotation(int[] rotatedCoordinates) {
        boolean valid = true;
        int counterX = 0, counterY = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            if(!tile[i].checkNewLocation(rotatedCoordinates[counterX], rotatedCoordinates[counterY])) 
                valid = false;
            counterX +=2;
            counterY +=2;
        }       
        return valid;
    }

    public void move()   {      
        if (movePieceValid()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                tile[i].setLocation(newPositionX[i], newPositionY[i]);              
            }       
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                tile[i].setLocation(currPositionX[i], currPositionY[i]);                
            }   
        }       
    }

    public void rotate(int[] rotatedCoordinates, String rotation) {
        int counterX = 0, counterY = 1;
        if (validRotation(rotatedCoordinates)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                tile[i].setLocation(rotatedCoordinates[counterX], rotatedCoordinates[counterY]);                
                counterX+=2;
                counterY+=2;
            }
        //else, if not valid move set the original location
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                tile[i].setLocation(currPositionX[i], currPositionY[i]);                
            }   
        }           
    }

    public boolean isCollision()    {
        boolean collision = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            if(tile[i].collision(newPositionX[i], newPositionY[i])) {
                collision = true;
            }
        }
        return collision;
    }

    //calc curr coordinates, send them to getRotation... which will create new piece based on coords
    public int[] calcRotation(String direction) {   
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            currPositionX[i] = tile[i].getX();
            currPositionY[i] = tile[i].getY();  
            System.out.println("Current position: (" + currPositionX[i] + "," + currPositionY[i]+")");
        } 
        return getRotation(currPositionX, currPositionY, direction);
    }

    public int[] getRotation (int coordinatesX[], int coordinatesY[], String direction) {

        int[] rotationDirection;

        int[] coordinates = new int[8];
        int[] origin = new int[2];
        int[] newCoordinates = new int[8];
        int[] resultCoordinates = new int[8];
        int[] finalCoordinates = new int[8];

        int vectorMatrix[][] = new int[2][4];

        //set either R(90) or R(-90) rotation matrix values:
        if (direction.equals("right")) {
            rotationDirection = new int[] {0, -1, 1, 0}; 
        }
        else {
            rotationDirection = new int[] {0, 1, -1, 0}; 
        }

        int counterX = 0, counterY = 1, x = 0;
        while (counterY < coordinates.length) {
            //add arrays coordinatesX and coordinatesY into a single array: coordinates 
            coordinates[counterX] = coordinatesX[x];
            coordinates[counterY] = coordinatesY[x];
            counterX+=2;
            counterY+=2;
            x++;
        }   

        //set origin so it rotates around center...
        if (shape.equals("RevZ")) {
            origin[0] = coordinates[6];
            origin[1] = coordinates[7];
        }
        else if (shape.equals("T")) {
            origin[0] = coordinates[4];
            origin[1] = coordinates[5];         
        }
        else {
            origin[0] = coordinates[2];
            origin[1] = coordinates[3];
        }


        //subtract origin from vectors
        System.out.println();
        counterX = 0;
        counterY = 1;
        while (counterY < newCoordinates.length) {
            //System.out.println(coordinates[counterX] + ", " + coordinates[counterY]);
            newCoordinates[counterX] = coordinates[counterX] - origin[0];
            newCoordinates[counterY] = coordinates[counterY] - origin[1];
            System.out.println("Translated coordinates: (" + newCoordinates[counterX] + ", " + newCoordinates[counterY] + ")");
            counterX+=2;
            counterY+=2;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("vector matrix:");

        //fill up vectorMatrix with coordinates
        int k = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
                vectorMatrix[row][col] = newCoordinates[k++];
            }
        }

        //print vectorMatrix:
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorMatrix.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int j = 0; j < vectorMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(vectorMatrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }

        int rotationMatrix[][] = new int[2][2];

        //fill up rotationMatrix
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("multiplicative matrix:");
        k = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
                rotationMatrix[row][col] = rotationDirection[k++];
                System.out.print(rotationMatrix[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }   

        //perform matrix multiplication
        int[][] result = multiplyMatrices(rotationMatrix, vectorMatrix);

        //print resulting matrix
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("result matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(result[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("]");
        }       

        //load new matrix coordinates back into array
        k = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
                resultCoordinates[k] = result[row][col];
                k++;
            }
        }       

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("result coordinates:");
        counterX = 0;
        counterY = 1;

        while (counterY < resultCoordinates.length) {
            finalCoordinates[counterX] = resultCoordinates[counterX] + origin[0];
            finalCoordinates[counterY] = resultCoordinates[counterY] + origin[1];
            System.out.print("("+finalCoordinates[counterX] + ", " + finalCoordinates[counterY]+")");

            counterX+=2;
            counterY+=2;
        }   

        return finalCoordinates;    
    }   

    public int[][] multiplyMatrices(int rotationMatrix[][], int vectorMatrix[][]) {
        int mA = rotationMatrix.length;
        int nA = rotationMatrix[0].length;
        int mB = vectorMatrix.length;
        int nB = vectorMatrix[0].length;
        if (nA != mB) throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");
        int[][] C = new int[mA][nB];
        for (int i = 0; i < mA; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nB; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < nA; k++) {
                    C[i][j] += (rotationMatrix[i][k] * vectorMatrix[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return C;
    }

    public int[] getShape(String shape) {

        if (shape.equals("L")) {
            //pieceCoordinates = new int[] {0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2}; 
            pieceCoordinates = new int[] {4, 0, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1}; 
        }
        else if (shape.equals("O")) {
            pieceCoordinates = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2};                              
        }
        else if (shape.equals("Z")) {

            pieceCoordinates = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2};                          
        }
        else if (shape.equals("RevZ")) {
            pieceCoordinates = new int[] {1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2};                          
        }
        else if (shape.equals("Bar")) {
            //pieceCoordinates = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1};
            pieceCoordinates = new int[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1};
        }
        else if (shape.equals("T")) {
            pieceCoordinates = new int[] {1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2};                  
        }
        else if (shape.equals("RevL")) {
            pieceCoordinates = new int[] {0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1}; 
        }
        return pieceCoordinates;
    }
}


import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

public class TileSscce {
    private BoardSscce board;
    private int currX, currY;
    private Color color;

    public TileSscce(BoardSscce b, int x, int y) {

        board = b;

        //when Tile is instantiated, set its position
        setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return currX; 
    }

    public int getY() {
        return currY;
    }

    public boolean checkNewLocation(int newX, int newY) {
          boolean newLocationOK = board.isOpen(newX, newY);
          return newLocationOK;
        }   

    public boolean collision(int newX, int newY) {
        boolean collision = this.getY() == ((board.getHeight()/board.getTileSize()))-2 || board.getTileAt(newX, newY) != null;
        return collision;
    }

    public void setLocation(int newX, int newY) {
        //  board.setTileAt(null, currX, currY);
            currX = newX;
            currY = newY;
            board.setTileAt(this, currX, currY); 
    }



    public Color getColor() {
        return setColor(color);
    }

    public Color setColor(Color myColor) {  
        color = myColor;
        return color;
    }


}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT----------**
I've tried implementing both ValarDohaeris and Svend Hansen's suggestions... Now the block is moving right when I press down, up when I press left, and down when I press right...

[image]

It seems to have to do with these methods in Board class which get and set tile locations...

```
// returns the tile at (x, y) or null if empty
public Tile getTileAt(int row, int col) {
    System.out.println("getTileAt: " + row + ", " + col);
    if(isValidCoordinate(row, col))
        return grid[row][col];
    return null;
}

// sets the tile at (x, y) to tile
public void setTileAt(Tile tile, int row, int col) {
    System.out.println("setTileAt: " + row + ", " + col);
    if(isValidCoordinate(row, col))     
        grid[row][col] = tile;
}
```

And in Piece class... movements are defined as:

```
public void movePieceCheck(int keycode) {   
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow()+1, tile[i].getCol(), i);                               
        }       
        clearCurrPosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            board.checkEndGame(tile[i].getRow(), tile[i].getCol());
        }   
        board.checkBottomFull();
        if (isCollision()) board.createNewPiece();
        move();
    }
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow(), tile[i].getCol()+1, i);
        }       
        clearCurrPosition();
        move();
    }
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow(), tile[i].getCol()-1, i);
        }       
        clearCurrPosition();
        move();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that fits the definition of a ShortSCC..

Comment: I've had similar confusions before, and found that it helped simply renaming x and y to i and j and thinking only of row/column numbers (rather than sometimes row/column numbers and sometimes as x/y coordinates). Of course, it doesn't solve the problem, but it might make it easier to find and avoid re-introducing in the future :)

Comment: @Growler How it is going? Did you succeed to fix coordinates problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
grid = new TileSscce[totalRows][totalCols];
```

So when you want to access `grid[x][y]`, you should check

```
x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < totalRows && y < totalCols
```

in `isValidCoordinate(x, y)`.

Comment: That now allows the blocked to go off the screen to the right (columns) and still doesn't allow it to move to the available rows below (10 and 11). Although now it doesn't throw an exception when I try to move down again.. it just won't move at all

Comment: and isn't my `x` on the x axis, so you'd need to check that against total columns (because x axis spans across columns), and my `y` is on the y axis, so you'd need to check that against `rows`  because y access spans down through all the rows... am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Emm... Quite interesting question. So to find out where the problem(s) may be I'll try to analyze your code a little bit...

You paste stack trace as

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Board.getTileAt(Board.java:177)
...
```

and at the same time the `getTileAt()`

```
// returns the tile at (x, y) or null if empty
public Tile getTileAt(int row, int col) {
    System.out.println("getTileAt: " + row + ", " + col);
    if(isValidCoordinate(row, col))//isValidCoordinate()? 
        return grid[row][col];
    return null;
}

public boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y) {
        return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < totalCols && y < totalRows; 
    }
```

... so the isValidCoordinate method return terms as

`x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < totalCols && y < totalRows`

...the method doesn't allow to avoid array *out-of-bounds* problems; Seems like you put wrong array element indexes.

**A.** As I can notice, you trying to put a classic math matrix on Java [][] arrays as

```
public void clearRow(int rowToClear) {
         for(int row = rowToClear; row > 0; row--) {
             for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {//<-- ?
                grid[col][row] = grid[col][row-1];
             }
         }
    }
```

... and here I must say that you should know that in **[][] arrays** *x,y* are backwards and it is *y,x* because :

- y (or classic i) - sub-array index (vertical)
- x (or classic j) - sub-array's element index (horizontal)

so you should use array index something this way `grid[y][x] or grid[i][j]`

As a useful tip, I recommend you to analyze your code for logic errors in this field...

**B.** According to your app screenshot as

[image]

... it seems like the *x,y* problem takes place here too because you trying to control y **(vertical)** coordinates but (in real) you  control x *(horizontal)* coordinates only :S It is still because of the *row,col* instead of a classic Java *(col,row or y,x)* [][] array index positions.

**C.** And again concerning to the wrong directions...

> ...up when I press left, and **down** when I press **right**...

```
if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow(), tile[i].getCol()+1, i);
        }       
        clearCurrPosition();
        move();
    }
```

Here I'll try to analyze the event as (*you press right but move down*)...

OK... according to one of your tasks **you need to move by x coordinate** (horizontally) but look closer... you make `tile[i].getCol()+1` so it is `newY` and, of course, it moves vertically :S In your case it really moves **down** because you make increment as **y++** ...

```
public void calcNewPosition(int newX, int newY, int currTile) {             
        newPositionX[currTile] = newX;
        newPositionY[currTile] = newY;
    }

    public void clearCurrPosition() {   
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            currPositionX[i] = tile[i].getX();
            currPositionY[i] = tile[i].getY();  
            board.setTileAt(null, currPositionX[i], currPositionY[i]);
        }   
    }  



public void move()   {      
        if (movePieceValid()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                tile[i].setLocation(newPositionX[i], newPositionY[i]);//<-- !            
            }       
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
                tile[i].setLocation(currPositionX[i], currPositionY[i]);                
            }   
        }       
    }
```

...as a conclusion, I may recommend to change code *(move right)* something this way...

```
if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getRow()+1, tile[i].getCol(), i);
        }       
        clearCurrPosition();
        move();
    }
```

*I hope my tips will help you to figure out what to look closer. Anyway, if you have some additional information please do comment my answer*

---

Report if that helped you

Answer (score 2):

This is based on x corresponds to columns and y corresponds to rows.
However grid is indexed by [row][col].

```
TileSscce grid[][] = new TileSscce[totalRows][totalCols]; // 12 => totalRows, 10 => totalCols

public int getWidth() {
    return totalCols * tilesize;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return totalRows * tilesize;
}
```

Following changes (based on your initial code - Sscce: - without later edits) will get rid of the exception and allow drawing till bottom of the board.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] != null) {
                g.setColor(grid[row][col].getColor());
                g.fillRect(col * tilesize, row * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize); // changed, check below snippet from fillRect documentation
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }
}

public TileSscce getTileAt(int x, int y) {
    if (isValidCoordinate(x, y))
        return grid[y][x]; // changed to [y][x] as grid is indexed by [row][col]
    return null;
}

public void setTileAt(TileSscce tile, int x, int y) {
    if (isValidCoordinate(x, y))
        grid[y][x] = tile; // changed to [y][x] as grid is indexed by [row][col]
}
```

From fillRect documentation.

```
public abstract void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1.
    The top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1.
```

This is correct.

```
public boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y) {
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < totalCols && y < totalRows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, swapping the x and y in grid[][] allows it to move down, but when I reach row 9 and try to move down again it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 at Board.getTileAt, at Tile.collision, at Piece.isCollision, at Piece.movePieceCheck, at Board.keyPressed...`

Comment: @Growler There might be other changes from your previous attempts causing the issue. I used your initial code (in Sscce:) without other edits added later. All I changed were `g.fillRect()`, `getTileAt()` and `setTileAt()` as indicated in comments above. Index at row 10 giving exception means, row/y col/x swap is still not complete.